# Xcode swift: global variable is empty

Tags: ios, swift, global-variables, global

here is my code that did not work:

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit

var systemLanguage = ""

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        // Systemsprache erkennen
        let systemLanguage = NSLocale.preferredLanguages()[0] as! String
        println("Device system language: \(systemLanguage)")

        return true
    }
```

settingsTableViewController.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        if systemLanguage == "de" {

            self.title = "Einstellungen"

        } else {

            self.title = "Settings"

        }
        println("Device system language: \(systemLanguage)")

        self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()

    }
```

When the app is starting the console says: *Device system language: de*

but when I change the view to settingsTableViewController the variable systemLanguage is empty. The console says: *Device system language:*

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why? Because of scope. You named a local variable the same as an instance variable. In your app delegate:

```
// Systemsprache erkennen
let systemLanguage = NSLocale.preferredLanguages()[0] as! String
println("Device system language: \(systemLanguage)")

return true
```

`systemLanguage` is deallocated the moment execution leaves that function. If you changed it to this it would work:

```
// Systemsprache erkennen
systemLanguage = NSLocale.preferredLanguages()[0] as! String
println("Device system language: \(systemLanguage)")

return true
```

Basically, you assigned to a different variable than what you were expecting.